Are questions on whether italian-language media (books, shows, etc.) are good examples of the language, on-topic for this site?
I ask because I know that there can be a great deal of regional variety in dialogue (I'm thinking dialects here), so if a movie or show takes place in Rome, for example, as a new learner I may not be 100% clued in that they are speaking in the Roman dialectical variant of the language, or whether it's standard Italian.
An example question could be "Is the Italian used in La Vita è Bella standard Italian or does it incorporate any dialects that I'd need to be aware of?"
Are questions of these types on-topic?

Well, I think the example question is a bit too broad, but with some care in posing it it could become a good question.

I think such questions are ok, if a bit borderline. It probably would help if you referred to a particular part of the movie or even a particular scene (after all, different characters might talk in rather different idiolects) but on the whole I don't see why it should be off topic.

Also, if you link to a youtube video of that scene, you will make the job easier for people who want to help you.
